# Input to be printed in different output format

Tags: oracle-12c, plsql

I have a value (e.g. ORACLE) and I would like to print each letter on an individual line using an Oracle query.

Input value:

```
ORACLE
```

Output:

```
O
R 
A
C
L
E
```

Answer (score 1):

With PL/SQL find the length of string first,use substring to extract each character and print with dbms_output

```
BEGIN
  FOR ctr in 1..LENGTH('ORACLE')
  LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR('ORACLE',ctr,1));
  END LOOP;
END;
```

or with declaring variables

```
DECLARE
l_str VARCHAR2(20):='ORACLE';
l_len INTEGER;
BEGIN
  l_len:=LENGTH(l_str);
  FOR ctr IN 1..l_len
   LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(l_str,ctr,1));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here is running pl/sql in sql*plus

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  l_str VARCHAR2(20):='ORACLE';
  3  l_len INTEGER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    l_len:=LENGTH(l_str);
  6    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Output:');
  7    FOR ctr IN 1..l_len
  8     LOOP
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SUBSTR(l_str,ctr,1));
 10     END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /
Output:
O
R
A
C
L
E

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in SQL by using a hierarchical query, e.g.:

```
WITH t AS (SELECT 'ORACLE' str FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'ROCKS' str FROM dual)
SELECT str,
       SUBSTR(str, LEVEL, 1) new_str
FROM   t
CONNECT BY PRIOR str = str
           AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
           and LEVEL <= LENGTH(str);

STR    NEW_STR
------ -------
ORACLE O
ORACLE R
ORACLE A
ORACLE C
ORACLE L
ORACLE E
ROCKS  R
ROCKS  O
ROCKS  C
ROCKS  K
ROCKS  S
```